# Hadoop copying local file to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to copy a local file called 'afile' to the HDFS.
So I ran the following command:

'hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/neo/afile in'
or 'hadoop fs -put /home/neo/afile in'

However, it says:
'File /home/neo/afile does not exist'

Then I put the file 'afile' into the directory under hadoop. Now the copyFromLocal succeeded. However, the file 'in' is empty, since I run
'hadoop fs - ls', it shows

'-rw-r--r--' 1 neo supergroup 0 2015-04-06 17:45 /user/neo/in

I also tried 'hadoop fs -cat in', nothing returned.

Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Share the output of the command " ls -ltr /home/neo/afile "

Comment: What does the `afile` contain? Also post the result for `ls -l /home/neo/`.

Comment: @h4ck3r    The result for command 'ls -ltr /home/neo/afile' is: '-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo 19 Apr 6 17:17 /home/neo/afile

Comment: @RajeshN The contents of a file is a simple text: 'to be or not to be'   The result for 'ls -l /home/neo' is :                                                            -rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo        19 Apr  6 17:17 afile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo         0 Apr  6 17:17 afile~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo        20 Apr  6 17:31 afile2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo         0 Apr  6 17:31 afile2~
drwxr-xr-x 2 neo neo      4096 Mar 30 12:12 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 neo neo      4096 Mar 30 12:12 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 5 neo neo      4096 Mar 30 21:47 Downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo neo      8445 Mar 30 11:24 examples.desktop

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new file in local filesystem named `test.txt` in `/home/neo/`
2. Add content to `test.txt`: `echo "sample text for wordcount" > /home/neo/test.txt`
3. Create a new directory in hdfs using: `hadoop fs -mkdir /user/neo/in/`
4. Copy file from local directory to HDFS: `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/neo/test.txt /user/neo/in/test.txt`

Comment: The file 'test.txt' can be copied to HDFS. However, it is still an empty file on the HDFS.

Comment: @NeoXU As you have said earlier `The contents of a file is a simple text: 'to be or not to be'`, add this content in your test.txt of local filesystem and then try to upload it to HDFS. If you get file already exists problem, do this `hadoop fs -rmr /user/neo/in/test.txt` and then try to upload.

Comment: Thanks so much! But still doesn't work. I still got an empty file.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Do `step 2` to add content to text file and then try to copy it from local filesystem to HDFS.