# Ingesting csv data to hadoop

Tags: csv, ubuntu, hadoop, data-ingestion

Currently I'm trying to ingesting data to hdfs. The type of data i was trying to ingest is csv. 
Hadoop 3.1.1 installed on ubuntu.
data sample stored on /home/hadoop/test.csv

## I've Tried

[source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277239/importing-csv-file-into-hadoop)

```
hadoop@ambari:~$ hdfs dfs -put /home/hadoop/test.csv user/data/test.csv
put: `user/data/test.csv': No such file or directory: `hdfs://xxxx:8020/user/hadoop/user/data/test.csv'
```

so i modify it into just test.csv and it returns

```
hadoop@ambari:~$ hdfs dfs -put /home/hadoop/test.csv test.csv
put: `test.csv': No such file or directory: `hdfs://xxxx:8020/user/hadoop/test.csv'
```

because It is written that no directory i follow another source to make a directory 
[source2](https://bigdataprogrammers.com/load-csv-file-in-hive/) 
[source3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481130/hadoop-copying-local-file-to-hdfs?rq=1)

```
hadoop@ambari:~$ hadoop fs -mkdir bdp
mkdir: `hdfs://xxxx:8020/user/hadoop': No such file or directory
hadoop@ambari:~$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hadoop/in
mkdir: `hdfs://xxxx:8020/user/hadoop': No such file or directory
```

Comment: `hdfs dfs -put user/data/test.csv /home/hadoop/test.csv`

Comment: hi there, thank you so much for your response. I've tried your suggestion and it returns :

Comment: put: `/home/hadoop/test.csv': No such file or directory: `hdfs://ambari.int.cbn.net.id:8020/home/hadoop/test.csv'

Comment: `hdfs dfs -put user/data/test.csv /home/hadoop`

Comment: have you tried ````hdfs dfs -ls /user ````  to see if path /user/hadoop exists? because if it doesn't exist, you will have to create it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing CSV file into Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277239/importing-csv-file-into-hadoop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@yuliansen

The command to copy a file from local disk to hdfs is as follows:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hadoop/test.csv /user/data/
```

If the folder is not created as hdfs or root user execute:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/data
```

If you are executing the hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal command as the user "data" then do this:

```
hdfs dfs -chown data:hdfs /user/data
```

If you are executing the command as user "hadoop" then you will need to make sure that /home/hadoop/test.csv and /user/data are both chowned to user hadoop:

```
chown hadoop:hadoop /home/hadoop/test.csv
hdfs dfs -chown hadoop:hdfs /user/data
```

Once you have the source file and hdfs location owned correct, then you can execute the hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal